# DirectX How can I clone a cube?

Tags: directx, cube, vertex

I have defined a cube as follows:

```
void cube(void){
struct CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] = 
    { 
      { D3DXVECTOR3(-0.5000f, -0.5000f,  0.5000f), //pos of first vertex
        D3DXVECTOR3( 0.0000f,  0.0000f,  1.0000f), //normal of first vertex
        D3DXCOLOR  ( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f),      //color of first vertex
        D3DXVECTOR2( 1.0000f,  1.0000f) },         //texture of first vertex

        // ...  data for other 35 vertices

    static short indices[]=
    // here are the indices

    //next I did:
    CreateVertexBuffer();
    CreateIndexBuffer();
```

In My `BeginScene();` I call:

```
        d3ddevice->SetStreamSource(0, vb, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));    
        d3ddevice->SetIndices(ib);
        d3ddevice->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 36, 0 , 12);
```

This gives me a cube made of 12 triangles and 36 vertices. Is there an easy way to multiply this values so I can get more same cubes as shown [here](http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/030/0/f/cube_by_nightkn8-d74c8tt.png). (sory for quality). I think that I should create 3 loops that will `DrawIndexedPrimitive`in x y z directions, but I don't know if I'm right, and don't know how to code it. "Invisible", overlapping and contacting edges are fine in this project so don't worry about them.

EDIT:
I have done it:

```
void cubes () {     
    float x      = 0.0;
    float y      = 0.0;
    float z      = 0.0; 
    int multiply = 9;

        for (int i=0;i<multiply*multiply*multiply;i++)
        {
            D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matM,x,y,z);
            d3ddevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(matM*matRotY*matRotX));
            d3ddevice->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 36, 0 , 12);
                x += 1.0f;
            if (x==multiply)
            {
              y += 1.0f;
              x = 0.0;
            }
            if (y==multiply)
            {
                  z +=1.0f;
              y = 0;
            }
        }
}
```

but the rotation point is in the lower corner of the "big cube" made of smaller cubes. Any idea how can I move it to the middle like [here](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/031/3/1/cu_by_nightkn8-d74gqu1.png) (the blue dot).

Comment: You don't want to clone the buffers. Define a translation world matrix and render the same buffer again. The approach with three `for` loops is fine. Is there anything specific you have questions about?

Comment: @NicoSchertler That would be fine given a small amount of cubes, but I think OP is looking towards voxel geometry rendering judging by the direction of his question. I could be wrong about that, but in that case, it would be better to pack 9x9x9x24 vertices and corresponding indices in one vertex and index buffer and draw from that single vertex buffer.